# XSLT for-each-group not supported in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm trying to transform an XML using the for-each-group element as such:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/orders">
        <myElem>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="order" group-by="identifier/value">
                <xsl:sort select="current()/date" order="descending" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" />
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </myElem>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My source document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <order>
        <identifier>
            <value>Order489</value>
        </identifier>
        <date>2016-08-10T15:39:16</date>
        <customer>
            <id>***</id>
            <address>***</address>
        </customer>
        ...
    </order>
    <order>
        <identifier>
            <value>Order490</value>
        </identifier>
        <date>2016-08-10T15:42:34</date>
        <customer>
            <id>***</id>
            <address>***</address>
        </customer>
        ...
    </order>
</orders>
```

No matter what I do the transformed XML ends up with an empty root element.

I have included the camel-saxon dependency in my POM and the feature is installed in the Karaf container.

My endpoint:

```
<to uri="xslt:/xsl/foo.xsl?transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl" />
```

I'm starting to think that this feature is not supported by the camel-saxon component. I find it strange that I'm not getting any errors until further down my route.

**Update**

I have now noticed that when I start my bundle I get the following stacktrace:

```
"select" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:for-each-group element!; Line#: 10; Column#: 99
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: "select" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:for-each-group element!
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.error(StylesheetHandler.java:904)[:]
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.error(StylesheetHandler.java:947)[:]
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.XSLTElementProcessor.setPropertiesFromAttributes(XSLTElementProcessor.java:347)[:]
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.XSLTElementProcessor.setPropertiesFromAttributes(XSLTElementProcessor.java:267)[:]
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.ProcessorLRE.startElement(ProcessorLRE.java:283)[:]
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.startElement(StylesheetHandler.java:623)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:917)[:]
    at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XsltBuilder.setTransformerSource(XsltBuilder.java:360)
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.loadResource(XsltEndpoint.java:342)
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.doStart(XsltEndpoint.java:396)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2869)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1097)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1058)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1054)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:574)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:200)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:533)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:494)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1025)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2895)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2618)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2467)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2486)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2432)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.start(BlueprintCamelContext.java:180)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.maybeStart(BlueprintCamelContext.java:212)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.serviceChanged(BlueprintCamelContext.java:150)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:943)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:794)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4445)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3431)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:353)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.init(BlueprintCamelContext.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:956)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:712)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:824)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:247)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:682)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:294)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:263)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:253)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[17:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1127)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:696)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:484)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2100)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.RestartBundle.doExecute(RestartBundle.java:45)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:37)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor169.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)[19:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl:1.0.4]
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)[19:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl:1.0.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.commands.$BlueprintCommand796348771.execute(Unknown Source)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:92)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:197)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.DelayedStarted.run(DelayedStarted.java:79)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-621084]
```

So, am I missing a dependency somewhere or is this plainly not supported in Camel as of now?

Comment: The snippet you have posted is not well-formed (the closing tag at the end should be `</orders>`). As for getting an empty root element, you don't output anything in your `for-each-group` other than doing `xsl:apply-templates` without having any specific templates, so you rely on built-in templates. I would help if you show which result you want to achieve.

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/ncntCRS/1 for an example that groups and sorts and also produces some output inside of the `for-each-group`.

Comment: Sorry, the xml is not the de facto document but a minified version for brevity, the actual file is not missing the end tag. I have updated my question with a stacktrace I just noticed, perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you describe suggest that the path expression `otherElem` is not selecting anything.

It's an odd path expression to find here, because if it does select anything it will only select one element (your context node is the root node "/", which can only have one element child), and if you've only got one element in a node-set then grouping it is rather pointless.

Show us your source document and your desired output, and we're more likely to be able to see where you've gone astray.

**Later**

You have now provided a source document and a stylesheet. After repairing your source document (the final end tag was wrong), the transformation produces the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myElem>

            Order490

        2016-08-10T15:42:34

            ***
            ***
         ... 

            Order489

        2016-08-10T15:39:16

            ***
            ***
         ... </myElem>
```

Doesn't look very useful, but it's certainly not the "empty root element" that you allege.

Comment: I've updated my question, hope it helps identifying my problem.

Comment: I have again updated my question, now with a stacktrace I noticed when starting my bundle.

Comment: Shame you didn't post the stack trace earlier. It reveals that you are running Xalan, not Saxon.

Comment: Yes, I regret not finding it earlier but I was so caught up in my workflow that I completely failed to look at the logs from the bundle-startup. I had been staring at my routes for so long that I missed the fact that I had indeed NOT been using the transformationFactoryClass-attribute on that particular endpoint, but a completely different one.